# Iframe breaking parent site

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I use the following to load an iframe which loads over a parent site, but sometimes, the parent breaks as a result of loading the iframe.

this is the iframe code which is launched from a bookmarklet on a bookmarks toolbar (it works if you want to test - I haven't formatted it so can easily be added to bookmark for testing)

```
javascript:(function(d){var%20modal=document.createElement('iframe');modal.setAttribute('src','http://9ammusic.com/test/bm2.html?url='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+'&page_title='+document.title);modal.setAttribute('scrolling','no');modal.setAttribute('name','my_modal');modal.className='modal';document.body.appendChild(modal);var%20c=document.createElement('link');c.type='text/css';c.rel='stylesheet';c.href='//9ammusic.com/css/iframe.css';document.body.appendChild(c);}(document));
```

This is an example of a page that breaks when the iframe spawns. I've checked css class names etc and none clash

http://www.toysrus.co.uk/Toys-R-Us/Learning/Electronic-Learning/LeapFrog-Tag-Junior-Green%280027249%29;jsessionid=C34152146B0577932EBF279B2D26A8D8.app01?searchPosition=10

I'm baffled as this is quite rare but not acceptable at all.

Any ideas why it breaks?

Comment: Can you be more specific about `breaks`?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Yeah it throws all the css out and some divs actually disappear - if you test it you'll see what i mean - can't create a fiddle for it unfortunately